# add text boxes to a view in android

Tags: android, text, view

I have a View in Android which is basically a large image, with many small images in it that can be dragged. I want to add an option to create text boxes inside this view also, i.e. for the user to be able to create a text bix, write in it, move it around, etc. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a text box on small images as disable to set, and for example setOnLongClickListener and enable it so you can provide user to write textbox... Then setOnTouchListener on every small images to move around on the big one.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lout);
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final TouchListener listen1 = new TouchListener();
    img.setOnTouchListener(listen1);

    DragListener listen2 = new DragListener();
    vg.setOnTouchListener(listen2);

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView lbl = new TextView(vg.getContext());
            lbl.setText(et.getText());
            lbl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0,0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lbl.setOnTouchListener(listen1);
            vg.addView(lbl);

        }

    });

}
```

Something like this...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this correctly... from what I see here, you are showing me how to drag around objects on a big image (am I incorrect?). That I already know how to do.. I need to be able to do the same thing via a text view, and that's where I get stuck.. right now looking at how to create the text view dynamically and not from within xml, because naturally I don't want it to appear on the screen unless the user needs it at the moment.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood then... You can try to set a label whenever user hits enter, or put simply a button and setOnClick... then move that label, i assume that it's just the same with moving around images.

Comment: Well, I got everything to work. Thank you very much for the effort!